# Can network admin see my browsing activities when I'm connected to my work VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, administrator, browsing

Long story short:

I work remotely from time to time but I have to connect to my work VPN.
Some sites are banned (FB, Twitter, porn sites etc.)

My kid wanted to log in to his FB account and he was denied (I bet that he is lying, he wanted to access some porn sites). Can the network admin see that there was an attempt to access these restricted sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If he was denied that means it went through your work network. If it went through your work network then your IT can see that a connection attempt was made and the attempt was blocked.

In fact it is very likely that someone in IT got a automated email from the monitoring system when the attempt to connect to a blocked site was made, most corporate level monitoring software will do that. I would recommend immediately telling your IT department what happened so they do not think you tried to connect to whatever site your son tried to connect to.